# Junit with exception handling

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a test case which I consider handling exception in it. I wrote it this way.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    int result = mymethod(a + b);
    try{
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

Is this the write way? I am a little bit confused as I have not done this before.

Comment: I just edit my question.

Comment: @Test(expected = "Exception_Class")  
are you seeking anything else

Comment: In the catch clause, you should add a call to fail.